# How can I create a delegate for an event where the target method has different parameters?

Tags: c#, delegates

How is the best way to dynamically create a delegate for an `Event`, where the target `MethodInfo` has different parameters that the `Event`?

Here is my class code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> refresh;

    public void AddHandlerToEventInfo(EventInfo eventInfo, string methodInfoName)
    {
        Type tDelegate = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;

        var sourceType = this.GetType();

        Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate, this, methodInfoName);

        MethodInfo addHandler = eventInfo.GetAddMethod();
        Object[] addHandlerArgs = { d };

        addHandler.Invoke(this, addHandlerArgs);
    }

    public void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Test()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the code to call `Class1`:

```
private void AddHandlers()
{
    var class1 = new Class1();
    var eventInfo = class1.GetType().GetEvent("refresh");
    class1.AddHandlerToEventInfo(eventInfo, "HandleEvent");

    class1.AddHandlerToEventInfo(eventInfo, "Test");
}
```

Here is the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot bind to the target method because its
>   signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the
>   delegate type.

The exception is occurring at the line:

```
Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate, this, methodInfoName);
```

I understand why the exception is occurring, the question is not about the exception, but how to create a delegate for the `Test` method.

Comment: Wrap the `Test` method with another method.

Comment: You're trying to create a delegate of a type that doesn't match the method. You can't do that.

Comment: @Tommy Can you please help with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapping method that directly call your `Test` method.

```
public void WrapTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Test();
}
public void Test()
{
    ...
}
```

Add the wrapping method instead.

```
class1.AddHandlerToEventInfo(eventInfo, "WrapTest");
```